# Rails before_save callback not stripping out comma from number properly

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3, callback, gsub

I'm storing a monetary value as an integer (cents) in the database and then formatting it on the view side.  However, when the user inputs something like "175,000" the value that gets stored in the DB is "175".  It seems to be stopping at the first comma and not storing the rest of the zeroes.  I've verified (with rubular) that the regex properly selects any non-zero or decimal values and leaves just the number.  I'm just not sure why it keeps stopping at the first comma.

```
# model
before_save :convert_amounts_to_cents

def convert_amounts_to_cents
  self.loan_amount = loan_amount.to_s.gsub(/[^0-9\.]/, "").to_i
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, 175 and 175.00 are represented the same way when you save it. The right most 00 are implicit.

Though, when you are displaying the info to the user, you can chose the amount of decimal digits through proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

That's old ActiveModel feature, it converts passed value to integer when you set the value, so `before_save` is too late in this case.

Try to override `loan_amount=` :

```
def amount=(amount)
  self[:amount] = amount.to_s.gsub(/[^0-9\.]/, "").to_i
end
```